# How to fix Sparkle Unable to check for Updates

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, sparkle

I'm trying to setup an auto-update feature using Sparkle in my Mac app using SwiftUI. I keep getting an Unable to check for Updates error.
[Updae Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpvzA.png)

I wasn't able to figure out how to fix it based on the documentation and I've not tried to set anything like this up before.

I'm not sure if I messed something up in my swift code or if my .xml file has an error. Or maybe something else. I've attached some of my code below.

Swift file:

```
final class CheckForUpdatesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var canCheckForUpdates = false
    
    init(updater: SPUUpdater) {
        updater.publisher(for: \.canCheckForUpdates)
            .assign(to: &$canCheckForUpdates)
    }
}

struct CheckForUpdatesView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var checkForUpdatesViewModel: CheckForUpdatesViewModel
    private let updater: SPUUpdater
    
    init(updater: SPUUpdater) {
        self.updater = updater
        
        // Create our view model for our CheckForUpdatesView
        self.checkForUpdatesViewModel = CheckForUpdatesViewModel(updater: updater)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Check for Updates…", action: updater.checkForUpdates)
            .disabled(!checkForUpdatesViewModel.canCheckForUpdates)
    }
}
```

xml file:

```
<rss xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>MacLibrary Update</title>
    <link>http://sparkle-project.org/files/sparkletestcast.xml</link>
    <description>Most recent changes with links to updates.</description>
    <language>en</language>
    <item>
      <title>Version 2.0</title>
       <link>https://themaclibrary.com</link>
       <sparkle:version>2.0</sparkle:version>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ <ul> <li>Added support for auto-update</li> <li>Search apps now available</li> </ul> ]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Sun, 12 Mar 2023 15:20:11 +0000</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://github.com/doorhinge-apps/The-Mac-Library/releases/download/v2.0-beta.3/MacLibrary.app.zip" length="3090000" type="application/octet-stream" sparkle:edSignature="0BE06q4Xll6v8BrvQIRTNnd700piitM/P5eteZJ1P1B+TDiU2x981+CDwY25tY8YrSwMt7ZGyoXQd92tbESGnX3c3ZmrKo+3OhtjxGTi14AqokyJrrcWkPSXdQisUjRx=="/>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
func isUpdateAvailable() throws -> Bool {
    guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
        let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
        let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
        let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
        throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo
    }
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any] else {
        throw VersionError.invalidResponse
    }
    if let result = (json["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String {
        return version != currentVersion
    }
    throw VersionError.invalidResponse
}

enum VersionError: Error {
    case invalidResponse, invalidBundleInfo
}

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do {
        let update = try self.isUpdateAvailable()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // show alert
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

try using this method works better , no need to use sparkle pod

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).